# RTK query not refreshing - why?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

I have a RTK query that's not refreshing it's core content after a delete mutation. Could anyone explain why ? It's not clear to me where the problem lies as there is not refresh request made at any point.

The code looks fine and it's pretty much the same I use in another API that's working. And on this second API I pass the same data (a list of items) and it's refreshing fine after a delete ; here's the code:

:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { Auth, API, Storage } from 'aws-amplify';

// Define a service using a base URL and expected endpoints
export const researchApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'researchApi',
    tagTypes: ['Research'],
    
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ 
        baseUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_RESEARCH,
        prepareHeaders: async (headers, { getState }) => {
            const token = (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken();
            headers.set('Authorization', `${token}`);     
            headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');       
            return headers;
        }
    }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({

      getResearch: builder.query({
        query: () => `research`,
        providesTags: ['Research']
      }),

      getResults: builder.query({
        query: (id) => `results?searchid=${id}`,
      }),

      addResearch: builder.mutation({
        query(keywords) {
            const data = {
                keywords: keywords
            }
          return {
            url: `research`,
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
          }
        },
        invalidatesTags: ['Research']
      }),

      deleteResults: builder.mutation({
        query(results) {

            // send array
            let sanitized;
            sanitized = results.filter(item => item);
            
            const data = {
                items: sanitized
            }
            //console.log('data: ', data);
          return {
            url: `removeresult`,
            method: 'DELETE',
            body: data
          }
        },
        invalidatesTags: ['Research']
      }),
      

    }),
  })
  
// Export hooks for usage in functional components, which are
// auto-generated based on the defined endpoints
export const {  useGetResearchQuery, useGetResultsQuery, useAddResearchMutation, useDeleteResultsMutation } = researchApi
```

I'm calling the query like this :

```
    const router = useRouter()
    const { kwd } = router.query
    const { data, error, isError, isLoading } = useGetResultsQuery(kwd);

    if(isLoading) {
        return ( 
            <>
                <Spinner animation="border"  size="sm" role="status" />{' '} Please wait while Loading...
            </>
        )
    }
```

Any idea would be very helpful as I'm completely lost with this...

Comment: How do you identify *if* it is refreshing? Do you look for (and not see) a request happening in the Network pane in the devtools?

Comment: Also: is the middleware set up?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm supposed to get a GET request on the API once the delete happened, which I'm not getting on the console

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so problem solved, I didn't add the correct parameters :

getResearch: builder.query({
query: () => `research`,
providesTags: ['Research']
}),

```
  getResults: builder.query({
    query: (id) => `results?searchid=${id}`,
     providesTags: ['Research'] // ========> THAT WAS MISSING
  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and also make sure you are returning the correct data from the mutation. Thanks.

Return the correct fields from the mutation. If the required the field, can be `id` is not returned from the mutation, then there will be no refresh.